# How to overriding font-size in a Dashboard in Superset

Tags: css, apache-superset

I tried to override the `subheader-line` class for Big Number chart on a dashboard:

[image]

I tried the "Edit CSS" option:

```
.subheader-line {
    font-size: 150%!important;
}
```

However, when I click "Save Changes", the page becomes unresponsive. How can I override the font size?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with:

```
.superset-legacy-chart-big-number .subheader-line {
text-align: center;
font-size: 100% !important; }
```

I also use Big number chart as well and it work.